# Table 'test_db.colors' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, docker, go, docker-compose

I am building an app using Docker, docker-compose, MySQL and Go.

When I attempt to test one endpoint I get the error **Table 'test_db.colors' doesn't exist**.

**It seems that the sql dump does not imported properly.**

But I can connect to the database, at least there is no error, which is created in the same `.sql` file.

When I start the app the terminal shows:

```
golang_app         | 2020/06/20 21:48:04 docker:docker@tcp(db_mysql:3306)/test_db

golang_app         | 2020/06/20 21:48:04 DB Connected
```

After I make a request to the endpoint I get:

```
2020/06/20 22:05:00 File: handlers.go  Function: main.testDBHandler Line: 26 Error 1146: Table 'test_db.colors' doesn't exist
```

The file structure is:

```
 ./
  |_app/
    |_docker-compose.yml
    |_Go/
      |_*.go
      |_Dockerfile
    |_MySQL/
      |_Dockerfile
      |_.env
      |_sql-scripts/
        |_test.sql
```

The contents of the files are listed below:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  fullstack-mysql:
    container_name: db_mysql
    build:
      context: ./MySQL
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - database_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - mysql-log:/var/log/mysql
      - mysql-conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ./MySQL/sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - fullstack

  app:
    container_name: golang_app
    env_file:
      - ./Go/.env
    build:
      context: ./Go
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - api:/usr/src/app/
    depends_on:
      - fullstack-mysql
    networks:
      - fullstack

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin_container
    depends_on:
      - fullstack-mysql
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=fullstack-mysql #Note the "mysql". Must be the name of the what you used as the mysql service.
      - PMA_USER=root
      - PMA_PORT=3306
      - PMA_PASSWORD=root
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    ports:
      - 9095:80
    restart: always
    networks:
      - fullstack
    links:
      - fullstack-mysql

volumes:
  api:
  database_mysql:
  mysql-log:
    driver: local
  mysql-conf:
    driver: local

networks:
  fullstack:
    driver: bridge
```

**app/MySQL/Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:8.0
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD)
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=$(MYSQL_PASSWORD)
ENV MYSQL_USER=$(MYSQL_USER)
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=$(MYSQL_DATABASE)
ENV MYSQL_PORT=$(MYSQL_PORT)
ENV MYSQL_DRIVER=$(MYSQL_DRIVER)
COPY ./sql-scripts/test.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 3306
```

**app/MySQL/.env**

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=docker
MYSQL_USER=docker
MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db
MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_DRIVER=mysql
```

**app/MySQL/sql-scripts/test.sql**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test_db;

CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'docker'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'docker';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON *.* TO 'docker'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `colors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `colors` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(2, 'black'),
(4, 'blue'),
(5, 'green'),
(3, 'red'),
(1, 'white'),
(6, 'yellow');
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strconv"
    "strings"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jimlawless/whereami"
)

func setConfig() {
    config = Configs{}
    config.cookieName = os.Getenv("COOKIE_NAME")
    config.cookieValue = os.Getenv("COOKIE_VALUE")
    age, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv("COOKIE_MAX_AGE"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(whereami.WhereAmI(), err.Error())
    }
    config.cookieMaxAge = age

    config.cookieHTTPOnly, err = strconv.ParseBool(os.Getenv("COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(whereami.WhereAmI(), err.Error())
    }

    config.cookiePath = os.Getenv("COOKIE_PATH")
    config.domain = os.Getenv("DOMAIN")
    config.port = os.Getenv("PORT")
    config.apiKey = os.Getenv("APP_KEY")
    config.apiVersion = os.Getenv("API_VERSION")
    config.apiPath = os.Getenv("API_PATH")
    config.protocol = os.Getenv("PROTOCOL")
    config.mysqlDB = os.Getenv("MYSQL_DATABASE")
    config.mysqlHost = os.Getenv("MYSQL_HOST")
    config.mysqlPassword = os.Getenv("MYSQL_PASSWORD")
    config.mysqlPort = os.Getenv("MYSQL_PORT")
    config.mysqlUser = os.Getenv("MYSQL_USER")
    config.mysqlDriver = os.Getenv("MYSQL_DRIVER")
}

func main() {
    defer recoverPanic()
    setConfig()
    err := db()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(whereami.WhereAmI(), err.Error())
    }

    routes()
}

func (fs FileSystem) Open(path string) (http.File, error) {
    f, err := fs.fs.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    s, err := f.Stat()
    if s.IsDir() {
        index := strings.TrimSuffix(path, "/") + "/index.html"
        if _, err := fs.fs.Open(index); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    return f, nil
}

func db() error {
    connStr:=config.mysqlUser+":"+config.mysqlPassword+"@tcp("+config.mysqlHost+":"+config.mysqlPort+")/"+config.mysqlDB
    log.Println(connStr)
    db, err := sql.Open(config.mysqlDriver, connStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(whereami.WhereAmI(), err.Error())
    }

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Ping Error: " + err.Error())
    } else {
        dbx.conn = db
        log.Println("DB Connected")
    }

    //log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s", dbx.conn), whereami.WhereAmI())
    return err
}

func recoverPanic() {
    if rec := recover(); rec != nil {
        err := rec.(error)
        log.Println(whereami.WhereAmI(), err.Error())

        var l *net.TCPListener
        file, err := l.File()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(whereami.WhereAmI(), err.Error())
        }

        path := os.Args
        args := []string{"-graceful"}

        cmd := exec.Command(path[0], args...)
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
        cmd.ExtraFiles = []*os.File{file}

        err2 := cmd.Start()
        if err2 != nil {
            log.Println(whereami.WhereAmI(), err2.Error())
        } else {
            log.Println(whereami.WhereAmI(), "Restarted...")
        }
    }
}
```

**handlers.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/jimlawless/whereami"
)

func testDBHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    id := 1
    var name string
    if err := dbx.conn.QueryRow("SELECT name FROM colors WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1", id).Scan(&name); err != nil {
        log.Println(whereami.WhereAmI(), err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, name)
}
```

Comment: you have two possibilities, first you have a tyo on one side, or you are connected rto the wrong database; MAKE A show tables; and see if the table is there

Comment: show tables;  gives me "no rows in result set"

Comment: then you are connected to the wrong server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to check:

1. Does the mysql container indicate that it started up correctly?
2. Is your mysql setup too complicated (see below)?
3. Have you tried connecting to your mysql instance with another application (e.g. datagrip, or some other mysql client?)
4. Have you ensured that mysql is actually done with it's startup process before you connect to it? `depends_on` may not really work properly here -- other application won't start up until after mysql starts, but mysql won't necessarily be configured yet -- i.e. your test.sql may not have actually run.

---

Your mysql setup seems somewhat complicated. Does it need to be? I've used a similar set of technologies and my docker compose for the database looked like this:

```yaml
  fullstack-mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - database_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - mysql-log:/var/log/mysql
      - mysql-conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ./MySQL/sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=docker
      - MYSQL_USER=docker
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db
      - MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - MYSQL_DRIVER=mysql
    networks:
      - fullstack
```

Assuming you don't need to do anything complicated, this should remove most of the mysql db setup.
The only other thing I did differently is map individual startup scripts, rather than the whole directory -- i.e.

```
volumes:
  ./MySQL/sql-scripts/test.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/test.sql
```

Though I think the folder mapping you have specified should work. One more bit I just noticed: in your mysql dockerfile, you do: `COPY ./sql-scripts/test.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` but this seems redundant with the docker-compose file, which places a volume in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization scripts on the entry point  are only run the first time the DB is created ( I.e. when the folder   /var/lib/mysql  is empty)

Delete the  database_mysql folder in your host machine and have docker-compose recreate it automatically. That will cause the scripts to run.

Note that all data stored in the DB will be lost when you delete the folder.